# how to prevent users from changing their username once their account is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm fairly new to rails, and I'm developing a small application that involves user accounts. Currently, the user is able to change/update their Name, Email, and Password. The user also has a unique Username, but I would like to prevent the user from changing it. How would I go about preventing this?

I've included the username in attr_accessible to allow for its creation when signing up, but I'd like to somehow remove this once the username is present. The only restriction I have so far is the lack of a username edit form, but I know this won't stop a creative user from issuing a PUT request to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to remove the parameter in the update action of the controller before they are passed into the `update_attributes` function, like below:

```
#UsersController
def update
  params[:user].delete(:username)
  @user = user.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated user."
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could use dynamic mass-assignment security as show in [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible), this gist being that you override the `mass_assignment_authorizer` function in the model to add any extra attributes that you want to be accessable to mass assignment.  Using that idea, you could do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible #what ever other stuff you wan't to accessable

  private
  def mass_assignment_authorizer
    new_record? ? super + [:username] : super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply reverse any attempted changes...

```
class User
  before_update :revert_username_if_changed, :if => Proc.new { |u| u.username_changed? }

  def revert_username_if_changed
    self.username = self.username_was
  end
end
```